# can't download excel in android webview using Download Manager

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-download-manager

I display web url in android webview. then on the web have a download report menu (.xls)

I've tried to use the download manager so I can download it through the webview that I created. but the result is always failed.

If needed this is my code

```
webview.setDownloadListener(object : DownloadListener {
            override fun onDownloadStart(url: String, userAgent: String, contentDisposition: String, mimetype: String, contentLength: Long) {
                val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype))
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...")
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype))
                val dm = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                dm.enqueue(request)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                registerReceiver(onComplete, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
            }


            var onComplete: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Downloading Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        })
```

[image: display from the report menu on the web]

[image: and this is my failed download notification display]

I have no other ideas, In advance thank you very much for all the help ^^

Comment: Is it because of .xls? Try to download a .jpg file as test.

Comment: @blackapps I've tried to download the image, and it worked. What should I check so that the generated excel file can be downloaded?