# Android WebView downloadListener is not working

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webview, android-download-manager

webview download listener is not work.

I have one website that contain download button, while clicking on button it generates download link for excel, while I click on download button it will successfully downloads excel via browser, but when i use webview it is not successful to download.

i already add permission in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i tried download image from other url and download is complete.

i also tried to check permission in my activity like this

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            Log.d("permission", "permission denied to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE - requesting it")
            val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            requestPermissions(permissions, 1)
        }
    }
```

and setDownloadListener is like this :

```
web.setDownloadListener(object : DownloadListener {
        override fun onDownloadStart(url: String, userAgent: String, contentDisposition: String, mimetype: String, contentLength: Long) {
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype))
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...")
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype))
            val dm = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            dm.enqueue(request)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            registerReceiver(onComplete, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
        }


        var onComplete: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Downloading Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    })
```

maybe you can check my question [can't download excel in android webview using Download Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70029879/cant-download-excel-in-android-webview-using-download-manager) and hope it can support the understanding of my problem

please help me, I just thinking maybe I have missed something to make it work. I am pretty new to this.
thank you very much for all help ^^

Comment: Try to download an xls (you did not mention xls) from anothet site. Or give the that same jpg file an xls extension

Comment: @blackapps I've tried redirecting to a different url to download the .xls file, but it still not successful
is there any code to add for it to work?

Comment: Your story does not make sense. DownloadManager is not interested in the mime type of a file. I downloaded a .jpg file. Went ok. Changed the extension to .jpg.xls and download went again ok. Now did you do that test? You did not even react!

Comment: @blackapps did you mean is double extension (.jpg.xls)? if yes, i’ve tried, but didn’t successfully